# How to get drag event for input of type range?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I run a JavaScript function every few milliseconds while an input with type range is having it's thumb dragged?

I'm currently using change, but it only fires once after the drag is over. I want to animate something as the drag is happening...

```
range.addEventListener('change', adjustPath, false)
```

Do I have to make the html element draggable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `"input"` event instead of `"change"`.  It should fire with every "tick" during the drag.  By "tick", I mean change in terms of what the slider is currently valued at during the drag.

Notice the difference between the first 2 inputs below.  The first will "tick" a lot more because there are more values along the slider.

The second has sparser values so you only see "input" when you actually drag in such a way that you are closer to the next value.

If you want a little bit more control than that, you can also attach mouse up/down/move listeners and add extra logic with respect to those.  Consider how the 3rd slider will log no matter how sparse the values are.

```js
function inputHandler() {
  console.log("input");
}

function changeHandler() {
  console.log("change");
}

const r1 = document.getElementById("r1");
r1.addEventListener("input", inputHandler);
r1.addEventListener("change", changeHandler);

const r2 = document.getElementById("r2");
r2.addEventListener("input", inputHandler);
r2.addEventListener("change", changeHandler);

const r3 = document.getElementById("r3");
let down = false;
r3.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
  down = true;
});
r3.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
  if (!down) return;
  console.log("mmove");
});
r3.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  down = false;
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label><span>R1</span> <input id="r1" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="20"></label>
<label><span>R2</span> <input id="r2" type="range" min="0" max="3" value="1"></label>
<label><span>R3</span> <input id="r3" type="range" min="0" max="3" value="1"></label>
```

Comment: Yes!!! Thanks for the simple elegant fix : ) I'm always learning more about web standards. It's amazing what you get straight out of the box these days.